# How do I access specific data from this array in Angular 10?

Tags: angular, angular10

I'm making a login app in angular 10 and now I need to somehow access the data, but I'm not sure how.

This is where I get my data. The method "getUsers" gets all the data.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { LoginModel } from '../models/login.model';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

  private url = 'api/user';

  // tslint:disable-next-line: variable-name
  private _users$ = new BehaviorSubject<LoginModel[]>([]);
  get users$(): Observable<LoginModel[]> { return this._users$.asObservable(); }


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


  getUsers(): Observable<LoginModel[]> {
    return this.http.get<LoginModel[]>(this.url)
      .pipe(
        tap(data => this._users$.next(data))
      );
  }

}
```

This is the model I use:

```
export interface LoginModel {
    userID: string;
    wachtwoord: string;
    admin: boolean;
  }
```

Now I want to access specific data from this in my login component, like for example the userID. In my logincomponent I imported the LoginService (the first code) so I can use the "getUsers" method (which returns an array), but how do I get the specific data from the array? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the `map` operator. Also, can you include some sample data to illustrate what exactly you want to fetch from it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to suscribe getUsers() either in component or wherever it is called as you are using HTTP observable

```
let userdetails:Array<LoginModel> = [];

 this.getUsers.subscribe((User) =>{
                  user.forEach(details =>{
                      //get details here                         
                   console.log(details.userID);
                   console.log(details.wachtwoord);
                   console.log(details.admin);
                   userdetails.push(details);
                      });//for each end
        },(error)=>{
        //handle error
       });
```

But since you are using rxjs tap and updating it to behaviour subject

There are two ways:

1.) subscribing to data when http calls are made. so that new data is constantly updated (recommended)

```
let userdetails:Array<LoginModel> = [];
this._users$.subscribe((user)=>{
  //new value comes here everytime http call is made
    //user is array so use forEach or map 
        user.forEach((detail)=>{ 
                   console.log(detail.userID);
                   console.log(detail.wachtwoord);
                   console.log(detail.admin);
                    }); 
      });
```

Note:- **dont forget to unsubscribe behaviour subject at ngondestroy(Angular life Ondestory life cycle hook). Forgetting to do so will cause memory leak**

```
ngondestroy() { this._users$.unsubscribe();  }
```

2.) second method is to get instant value of behaviour subject. It is not recommended as you will get only at the moment value states need to be managed

```
let userdetails:Array<LoginModel> = this._users$.getValue(); //gives instant value
```

better solution is do it inside the getUser call like this

```
let userdetails:Array<LoginModel> = [];

    this.getUsers.subscribe((User) =>{
                          //detailshere
  userdetails = this._users$.getValue();//value update
             userdetails.forEach((detail)=>{ 
                  console.log(userdetails.userID);                       
                  console.log(userdetails.wachtwoord);
                  console.log(userdetails.admin);
                        }); 
 
                },
              (error)=>{
                //handle error error
               });
```

https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject#getvalue-